# Are there router, network, or other settings that would prevent in-game chat from working?

Tags: windows, networking, router, gaming

I seem to be unable to speak in-game chat for any PC game, after trying on Halo Infinite, CoD MWII, and CoD Cold War.

- I can hear other players, they cannot hear me
- I've gone through in-game settings to death, and everything appears to be enabled to allow me to in-game chat
- Correct mic is selected in Windows
- Mic works for Discord and other programs, I can speak and be heard everywhere except for in-game chat
- PC connected to internet via Cat6 cable to Netgear R6400V2 router (PC has no wifi)
- Router is connected to an Arris Surfboard 6141 modem

Are there router or other settings I should be looking at that would enable me to speak and be heard through in-game audio?

Comment: Try to disable firewalls and your security software.

Comment: I can't help but think you are barking up the wrong tree here.

Comment: if you are connecting through SSH, that is not possible. It happened to me b4 though, check if you are connecting through a SSH or VPN